# Print an existing PDF file through an existing PrinterJob

Tags: java, swing, pdf, printing

This is a very basic functionality which I'm trying to implement. All I want is to print a PDF file through a given printer.
This is what I have tried so far

```
 File pdfFile = new File(pdfFileLocation);



 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
 Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);


 DocPrintJob pj = job.getPrintService().createPrintJob();

 pj.print(pdfDoc,new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
```

**NOTE :** *I want to achieve this without any third party libraries*

At the moment it complains corrupted when trying to print to the ONE-NOTE